# Wikipedia API: how to get the number of revisions of a page?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, wikimedia

Anyone know how to get the number of revisions of a wikipedia page using mediawiki API?
I have read this API documentation, but can't find the related API:
[Revision API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#revisions_.2F_rv)

Answer (score 9):

The only possibility is to retrieve all revisions and count them. You might need to [continue the query](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Continuing_queries) for that.

[Bug 17993](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17993) is about including a count, but is still unsolved.

Answer (score 4):

Here is code to get number of revisions of a page (in this case, the [JSON wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)):

```py
import requests

BASE_URL = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
TITLE = 'JSON'

parameters = { 'action': 'query',
           'format': 'json',
           'continue': '',
           'titles': TITLE,
           'prop': 'revisions',
           'rvprop': 'ids|userid',
           'rvlimit': 'max'}

wp_call = requests.get(BASE_URL, params=parameters)
response = wp_call.json()

total_revisions = 0

while True:
  wp_call = requests.get(BASE_URL, params=parameters)
  response = wp_call.json()

  for page_id in response['query']['pages']:
    total_revisions += len(response['query']['pages'][page_id]['revisions'])

  if 'continue' in response:
    parameters['continue'] = response['continue']['continue']
    parameters['rvcontinue'] = response['continue']['rvcontinue']

  else:
    break

print parameters['titles'], total_revisions
```

You can check the result here: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=JSON&action=info#Edit_history

(accessible from the corresponding wikipedia page sidebar: Tools - Page information)

Comment: I tried this piece of code and it keeps on running and never cease to execute

Comment: That was 2016 and API may have changed since then :) Not sure though

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve the revisions and implement a method to count them (It's just XML).

[MediaWiki Revisions: Example](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#Revisions%3a_Example)

```
api.php ? action=query & prop=revisions & titles=API|Main%20Page & rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content
```

.

```
<api>
<query>
<pages>
  <page pageid="1191" ns="0" title="API">
    <revisions>
      <rev user="Harryboyles" timestamp="2006-10-31T05:39:01Z" comment="revert unexplained change: see talk ...">
        ...content...
      </rev>
    </revisions>
  </page>
  <page pageid="11105676" ns="0" title="Main Page">
    <revisions>
      <rev user="Ryan Postlethwaite" timestamp="2007-06-26T19:05:06Z" comment="rv - what was that for?">
        ...content...
      </rev>
    </revisions>
  </page>
</pages>
```

Comment: This is a very expensive way to get the number of revisions.  You're requesting a lot of data (page contents, edit summaries) that you're just throwing away.

Answer (score 1):

With [REST API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:REST_API) provided by [newer MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:REST_API#API_comparison)s, you can use [the "Get page history counts" API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:REST_API/Reference#Get_page_history_counts) to get the number of revisions of a page.

For example,

```
GET https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/page/Jupiter/history/counts/edits?from=384955912&to=406217369
```

this request will return a JSON response like the following:

```
{
    "count": 110,
    "limit": false
}
```

Zero coding at all.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Wint's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136343/wikipedia-api-how-to-get-the-number-of-revisions-of-a-page/70517281#70517281), the best solution is probably to use the REST API.

Though, if you have to use the usual [Action API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page), your only solution is to count the revisions (which obviously will be slow on pages with large histories).

I have just crafted a JavaScript code for this:

```js
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
/* globals Promise, mw */

function countRevisions( pageTitle ) {
    return new Promise( function ( resolve, reject ) {
        mw.loader.using( 'mediawiki.api', function () {
            const api = new mw.Api();
            const userGroups = mw.config.get( 'wgUserGroups' );
            const apiLimit = userGroups.includes( 'sysop' ) || userGroups.includes( 'bot' ) ? 5000 : 500;
            let count = 0;
            function makeRequest( apiContinue ) {
                const params = {
                    action: 'query',
                    prop: 'revisions',
                    titles: pageTitle,
                    rvprop: '', // we don't need any property
                    rvlimit: apiLimit,
                    formatversion: 2,
                };
                if ( apiContinue ) {
                    Object.assign( params, apiContinue );
                }
                api.get( params ).done( function ( data ) {
                    if ( !data.query ) {
                        reject();
                        return;
                    }
                    const revisions = data.query.pages[ 0 ].revisions;
                    if ( revisions ) {
                        count += revisions.length;
                    }
                    if ( data[ 'continue' ] ) {
                        makeRequest( data[ 'continue' ] );
                    } else {
                        resolve( count );
                    }
                } ).fail( function () {
                    reject();
                } );
            }
            makeRequest();
        } );
    } );
}

countRevisions( 'Page title' ).then( function ( count ) {
    /* ... */
} );
```