# Wikipedia API: Get revisions by timeframe

Tags: python, api, wikipedia

I'm trying to figure out how to get all of the page revisions for a specified timeframe. I have created a python script which allows me to get the last 100 revisions, but I don't see anything that allows me to specify a timeframe. I do see the following parameters:

```
rvstart: Timestamp to start listing from. (enum)
rvend:   Timestamp to end listing at. (enum)
```

However, I'm not able to get these to work. They work if I put in a timestamp that exists as a revision timestamp, but not as an arbitrary range from which to encapsulate.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

Here is my script, if you're interested:

```
import json

from wikitools import wiki, api

site = wiki.Wiki("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php")
names = ["Sherrod Brown","Maria Cantwell"]
allMembers = []
for name in names:
    params = {'action':'query',
        'titles': name,
        'prop':'revisions',
        'rvprop':'ids|flags|timestamp|userid|user|size|comment|tags',
        'rvlimit':'100'
    }
    req = api.APIRequest(site, params)
    res = req.query(querycontinue=False)
    allMembers.append(res)

with open('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/python/wikipedia-1.4.0/data/wiki-leg.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(allMembers, outfile, indent=2)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136343/wikipedia-api-how-to-get-the-number-of-revisions-of-a-page?rq=1

Comment: @Ajay - I saw this, but this doesn't answer the question about setting a range min/max timeframe for which to search for revisions.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906739/api-to-get-wikipedia-revision-id-by-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API to get Wikipedia revision id by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906739/api-to-get-wikipedia-revision-id-by-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got it figured out.  The two parameters in highlighted in the OP:

```
rvstart: Timestamp to start listing from. (enum)
rvend:   Timestamp to end listing at. (enum)
```

have to be used in conjunction with:

```
rvdir: Direction to list in. (enum)
    older: List newest revisions first (default) NOTE: rvstart/rvstartid has to be higher than rvend/rvendid
    newer: List oldest revisions first NOTE: rvstart/rvstartid has to be lower than rvend/rvendid
```

So, updating the params to:

```
params = {'action':'query',
        'titles': name,
        'prop':'revisions',
        'rvprop':'ids|flags|timestamp|userid|user|size|comment|tags',
        'rvlimit':'100',
        'rvstart':'2009-01-01T12:00:00Z',
        'rvend':'2014-12-31T23:59:00Z',
        'rvdir':'newer'
    }
```

appears to achieve the intended purpose.